# Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause :- no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, tomcat

I am developing a java web application using tomcat and sqlserver IDE eclipse. I have downloaded sqljdbc.jar and added it in the project. I have also added the sqljdbc_auth.dll in the location java>jre1.8>bin. still i am getting the error -

Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause :- no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.

I did not getting the correct issue for this. Please help me as soon as possible. It will be grateful for me.

I have googled for it but did not get any satisfactory answer.

Code for connection:

```
  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
  System.out.println("SQL Server Loaded Succesfully");

  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;"
                   + "databaseName=Multibings;integratedSecurity=true");

  if(con != null){
   System.out.println("con created:::::"+con);
  }else{
      System.out.println("connection not created...");
  }
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Investigate the value of the system property `java.library.path`

Comment: Thanks for reply. What to incestigate in java. Library. Path??? Can you please explain in detail??

Comment: I have got this comment as suggestions many times when searched for this issue. But i am understanding where to check this nad how to check this?? So please explain in detail.

Comment: What is the value of the system property?

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions?

Comment: In _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_, in the _Native library location_ subnode of `sqljdbc.jar` specify the directory that contains `sqljdbc_auth.dll`.